# How to send messages every 5 seconds by aiogram?

Tags: python, bots, aiogram

I need a telegram bot which can send "Hello" every 5 seconds. I tried, but my script does totally nothing. Help me, please

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import schedule

bot = Bot(token) #here is my token
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def send(message : types.Message):
    await message.answer('Hello')

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(send)

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

from time import sleep

This code calls the send function every 5th second 10 times

```
for _ in range(10):

   send()
   sleep(5)
```

This code calls the send function basically forever but still in a five-second interval.

```
while True:

   send()
   sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try websockets?

```
import websockets
import asyncio
async def server(ws:str, path:int):
    while True:
        message = await ws.recv()  # or "Hello"
        print(f'Msg [{message}]')
        message_to_send = main(message)
        schedule.every(5).seconds.do(await ws.send(message_to_send))

server = websockets.serve(server, '127.0.0.1', 5678)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```